# How to define the DataObject of a DataWindowChild?

Tags: powerbuilder

My function has an input argument adwc of the type DataWindowChild. Is it possible to somehow discover its DataObject? There is no pointer to the DataWindow where the DWC is placed so we cannot ask for the field’s "dddw.name".

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,do you want to get the DatawindowChild's dataobject or the parent's dataobject?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the answer is no. You can do a adwc.Describe("datawindow.syntax") to get it's definition (or any Describe() to get various attributes), or, as you suggest, you can modify your function to take a handle to the parent and the column name to access the dddw.name.

What's the objective? Maybe if we knew the end game, we could make more valuable suggestions.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write code that cares about the name of the DataWindow object. There are several reasons.

1. The DataWindow is a dynamic object. The name a DataWindow control reports for the data object is the last one that was set by name. A completely different DataWindow can be loaded via Create and the name won't change.
2. Code that checks the DataWindow name is fragile. Suppose your code is checking if the dddw is `d_emp` or `d_manager`. When someone makes a new manager dddw and names it `d_manager_v2` your code may fail in an unexpected and confusing manner.
3. Your code that cares about the DataWindow name may violate design principles like [One Responsibility](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneResponsibilityRule).

Added based on Ursego's comments

For your DataWindow/DataStore you have `uf_row_exists(ls_search_expr)`. You're trying to write a function for DataWindowChild, but a DataWindowChild doesn't exist without a DataWindow Control, anymore than a DataWindow does. If you add `uf_child_row_exists(ls_column, ls_search_expr)` to your DataWindow/DataStore, you will have both the parent and the child.

Comment: It's a framework function which performs a search in DWC by an expression (here - http://forum.powerbuilder.us/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=83 - you can find a similar function but for DataWindow, not for DWC). If the search technically failed, the function throws an exception which displays the search expression and suggests to make sure that all the fields, mentioned in the expression, appear in the DataObject (to simplify finding the bug reason). But everything you have written is correct for business coding.

Comment: I've added to my answer based on your comment.